# Ways to pass information from PHP to JQUERY?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having a hard time figuring out what is the best way to transfer information from PHP to Jquery. I know putting PHP in Javascript is a really bad alternative (my JS and PHP files are seperated anyway), so what I usually do is print the info with PHP in the HTML with a input type hidden and retrieve the info in JQuery using the element.text() or .val() or any other method, but I feel this is kind of noobish. Is there a better way?

Comment: Depending on what the data is, if your PHP outputs HTML you can use data-* tags which jquery (and regular JS) can get. This amounts to the same as using hidden form fields though. Example: <p data-attrib-from-php="foobar">...</p>

Comment: Two obvious methods that are better than what you're doing at present: include your data as a javascript variable in a `<script>` tag; or make an AJAX call from your script to get the data after the page has loaded.

Comment: I often do as @andrewb above suggested, but now typically include this type of information in a <script> tag. In either case, I prefer to assemble all the data I plan on passing to the client into a dictionary/array on the server side, convert to JSON string, and embed in the HTML document where appropriate. This allows the data to be 'discoverable'.

Comment: What do you mean by include the information in a script?

Comment: [use `[data-*]` attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr/7262427#7262427)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend never using a server-side language to build JavaScript. Instead, keep your data in HTML (model), your styles in CSS (view), and your interactions in JS (controller).

When you need to pass data to JavaScript, make good use of attributes and templates.

When it comes to passing data via attributes, you can go a long way with just using native attributes.

In this example, it is quite apparent that the link will open a modal, and the `[href]` attribute is used to point to where the modal lives:

```
<a href="#modal" class="modal-link">Open modal</a>
<div id="modal">lorem ipsum</div>
```

When you can't fit data within native attributes, you should make use of [`[data-*]` attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

In this example, `[data-tooltip]` is being used to store a rich-text tooltip.

```
<div data-tooltip="&lt;p&gt;lorem ipsum&lt;/p&gt;">...</div>
```

Even more importantly, jQuery automatically grabs and casts all `[data-*]` attributes on a DOM node when `.data()` is called on the node.

```
<div id="example"
    data-foo="bar"
    data-fizz="true"
    data-max="100"
    data-options="{&quot;lorem&quot;:&quot;ipsum&quot;}">
    ...
</div>
<script>
    $('#example').data();
    /*
    {
        foo: 'bar',
        fizz: true,
        max: 100
        options: {
            lorem: 'ipsum'
        }
    */
</script>
```

The thing to watch out for is JSON encoding within HTML encoding. jQuery makes it very straight-forward to get the data out of the DOM node without needing to worry about decoding, but in PHP you need to make sure that you [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) data before calling [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
<div data-example="<?= htmlentities(json_encode($someArray)) ?>">...</div>
```

[In some instances you may want to make use of jQuery's `.attr()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr/7262427#7262427).

---

For large amounts of data, such as an HTML template string, you can use `<script>` tags with a template mime type (such as `type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"`):

```
<script id="template-example" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <h1>${title}</h1>
    <p>${body}</p>
</script>
```

Or you can use the [HTML5 `<template>` element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-template-element):

```
<template id="template-example">
    <h1>${title}</h1>
    <p>${body}</p>
</template>
```

You can then access the HTML contents of the element run it through whatever your favorite flavor of string templating happens to be.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply echo PHP variables into Javascript variables for your jQuery to use like this:

```
<?php
$stringVar = "hi";
$numVar = 1.5;
?>

<script>
var stringVar = "<?php echo $stringVar; ?>";
var numVar = <?php echo $numVar; ?>;
</script>
```

This can be used for practically any data type as long as you convert it correctly upon echoing it (oftentimes `json_encode()` is enough for complex structures such as arrays and objects).

Also note that this way will only work if your jQuery code is included after these variables have been defined.

The other way is to look into using AJAX, but if these are static variables that don't need to change within the lifetime of the page then I would go with the method above.

Comment: Isn't it a bad method to inject php in some javascript? Also, my external js is linked in my head, so I would have to do that just before the script src tag?

Comment: Correct, it would have to be somewhere before the script tag you use to include the js file. I rely on this method regularly in my own projects. I ensure that all data passed this way is checked and escaped where necessary, and otherwise it is fine to use.